# Lost Connection to mysql server at 'reading authorization packet', system error 0"

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

OK, this has been bugging me all afternoon now,

I have a new MySQL Database '5.5.40-0+wheezy1-log' running on Debian Linux. It is to all extents and purposes a clean install.

I have created two users:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'test'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'test';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'a_secure_password';
```

I am trying to connect from my PC (windows 7)

- If I connect to the physical server (via Putty) I can log into MySQL fine using both usernames.
- If I use (the now obsolete) MySQL Query Browser, I can log into MySQL fine using both usernames.
- If I use the new MySQL Workbench (6.2)

  - I can only log in using the 'test' user.
  - If I try the 'root' user I get : `Your Connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at '123.456.789.123:3306' Lost Connection to mysql server at 'reading authorization packet', system error 0`

Why? it's driving me round the bend.